# My default tab controller does not refresh its tabs content

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs, refresh

I have an app that has a main bottom tab (`bottomNavigationBar` of a `scaffold`).

Inside each tab, I have a top tab bar controller which is set whenever the user tap on a given tab of the bottom nav bar which changes the `TabBarView` child `tabSectionBodies` accordingly (see my code below);

This layout is a new which I implemented to improve the UX.

But what I see now, is that there's no updates of the inner tab when the state changes.

Meanwhile, the logs show the `refreshCount` is increasing:

```
I/flutter (26204):  OlenBoxDashboard: Dashboard refresh: 1010
I/flutter (26204):  OlenBoxDashboard: Dashboard refresh: 1011
I/flutter (26204):  OlenBoxDashboard: Dashboard refresh: 1012
I/flutter (26204):  OlenBoxDashboard: Dashboard refresh: 1013
```

The `Widget build()` is as follows:

```dart
Widget build() {

    // Code has been stripped out for better understanding of the rest

    refreshCount++;
    log("Dashboard refresh: $refreshCount");

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: tabSectionBodies.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(isScrollable: true, tabs: tabSectionTabs),
          title: Text(deviceDisplayName),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(children: tabSectionBodies),

        /// The main (bottom) tab bar
        bottomNavigationBar: Material(
          color: Colors.indigo,
          child: TabBar(
            onTap: (index) {
              log("BottomNavigationBar: index is $index");

              if (index == 0) {
                setState(() {
                  setupBatteryBottomTab();
                });
              } else if (index == 1) {
                setState(() {
                  tabSection = "BMS";
                  tabSectionTabs = [
                    Tab(text: "Main"),
                    Tab(text: "Commands"),
                    //...
                  ];
                  tabSectionBodies = [
                    buildDashboardBatteryBms(0),
                    // ...
                    buildDashboardBatteryBms(6),
                  ];
                });
              } else if (index == 2) {
                setState(() {
                  tabSection = "Smartbox";

     // Code is longer and has been cut off…
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I pinpointed the issue.

The overall structure is OK, except that the `tabSectionBodies` var is assigned by the content of the tabview with the state at the moment of the assignment:

```dart
tabSectionBodies = [
                    buildDashboardBatteryBms(0),
                    // ...
                    buildDashboardBatteryBms(6),
                  ];
```

What I did to fix the problem, is to set a function that returns the Widgets at build time as follows:

```dart
tabSectionBodies = () => [
                    buildDashboardBatteryBms(0),
                    // ...
                    buildDashboardBatteryBms(6),
                  ];
```

And the question snippet becomes:

```dart
Widget build() {

    // Code has been stripped out for better understanding of the rest

    refreshCount++;
    log("Dashboard refresh: $refreshCount");



    final _tabSectionBodies = tabSectionBodies();


    return DefaultTabController(
      length: _tabSectionBodies.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(isScrollable: true, tabs: tabSectionTabs),
          title: Text(deviceDisplayName),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(children: _tabSectionBodies),

        /// The main (bottom) tab bar
        bottomNavigationBar: Material(
          color: Colors.indigo,
          child: TabBar(
            onTap: (index) {
              log("BottomNavigationBar: index is $index");

              if (index == 0) {
                setState(() {
                  setupBatteryBottomTab();
                });
              } else if (index == 1) {
                setState(() {
                  tabSection = "BMS";
                  tabSectionTabs = [
                    Tab(text: "Main"),
                    Tab(text: "Commands"),
                    //...
                  ];
                  tabSectionBodies = () => [
                    buildDashboardBatteryBms(0),
                    // ...
                    buildDashboardBatteryBms(6),
                  ];
                });
              } else if (index == 2) {
                setState(() {
                  tabSection = "Smartbox";

     // Code is longer and has been cut off…
```